# how to get model variable in phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, module, model

model

```
public function getAvaiableCustomerCredit()
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
        $customer_credit = $this->getBaseCustomerCredit() - $session->getBaseCustomerCreditAmount();
     return round($store->convertPrice($customer_credit), 3);
    }
```

i want to call `$customer_credit` in phtml file. what should i do. anyone can help  me.

Answer (score 2):

We are not sure what you really want to achieve as your question is bit unclear.

If you want to call a method in a model, then you need to instantiate your model with Magento factory methods :

```
$model = Mage::getModel('ModelGroup/PathToEntity');
```

Where you need to use correct model group and entity path. For example to get the product model, what you need to do is:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

Once you have you model isntance, then you can invoke any public method of model entity like this :

```
 $result =  $model->getAvaiableCustomerCredit();
```

I believe you need to study basics concept of Magento first.

Comment: this is function in model.php in this function i am using variable $customer_credit now i want to call this variable to phtml file

Answer (score 1):

Define this function in the Block of your module and you can get this in your .phtml file using `$block->getAvaiableCustomerCredit()`

Comment: same function i call in my block and fallow your code for .phtml file but i did not get solution

Comment: Strange... are you able to get value for other functions available in your block file? If not, then you are calling wrong file. Place you code in the correct block file. Check layout file for your block file location.